# Honda Civic starting problems?

Tags: honda, electrical, starting, civic

my honda doesn't want to start, in the morning it starts with one crank but as soon as I drive and I switch off the car and I want to start again then it doesn't want to start. When I take a piece of wire on positive connector on starter and other end on the starter (where the starter wire is) then it starts.   I do not know what the problem with it is. It's a 2000 model honda ballade vtec shape

Does somebody know why my car won't start?

Please help.

Comment: I think your procedure needs a little more explanation.  All I can think of are very bad consequences when I read _"but when I take a pice of wire then I put it on the starter"_...

Comment: You are saying when the engine is hot and you turn the key, *nothing* happens? No crank situation. Yet, when you jump the solenoid with a wire, it starts just fine?

Comment: Model year?  Also, if you register yourself as a use you wil have an account and communication could be easier for you.   Here is a link to the tour.   http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour  You can see how the site works.  Cheers.

Comment: Yes that's it and sometimes it starts fine when it's hot nd sometimes not

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your starter solenoid is bad.  You starter solenoid has two pieces to it.

- The signal it takes from your ignition switch triggers a magnet the turns another switch
- when the magnet is activated it closes another circuit for your starter.  This gives your starter current from the battery to turn over your engine.

If I get what your saying, you are manually activating your starter with a wire to turn over your engine which means your starter is ok.

Based on the info I would guess that your either your starter solenoid or ignition switch are where the issue resides.

Mind you this is a guess based upon limited info.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34627/discussion-on-answer-by-ducatikiller-honda-civic-starting-problems).